# Log out origin IP of nginx.request in GCP?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My app looks like it is logging a significant amount of GET requests to my homepage (for an app which is still in test), about 1-2 per minute. Is there a builtin mechanism in Google Cloud to figure out where these are coming from, IP-wise?

[image: My logs looks like this, with 'GET received... Homepage being lines in my app that I will probably move to a lower loglevel since GCP does this automatically]